# Order wp_query by numeric custom field

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to allow users to sort a list of results from a `wp_query` by a numeric custom field value. Users can click a button to change the sort by values, but when Price is selected, this is what the `wp_query` looks like:

```
'meta_key' => 'adult',
'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
'order' => 'ASC',
```

The field is the numeric field from ACF (ACF 5 beta is being used) with a `step` size of `0.01` to allow for prices like 9.99.

However, if I run this query it returns no results every time, even when there are definitely results that should be matching.

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

EDIT - full query

```
$keywordString = $_SESSION['search']['keyword'];
$keywords = explode(', ', $keywordString);

$taxQuery = array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
    array (
        'taxonomy' => 'main-cat',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => $_SESSION['search']['cat']
    )
);

if( $_SESSION['search']['keyword'] != '' ) {
    $taxQuery[] = array(
        'taxonomy' => 'sub-cat',
        'field' => 'name',
        'terms' => $keywords
    );
}

$args = array(
    // general
    'post__in' => $postIDs,
    'post_type' => 'event',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'paged' => $paged,
    'cache_results' => false,

    'meta_key' => $_SESSION['search']['sort-key'], // becomes 'adult'
    'orderby' => $_SESSION['search']['sort-by'], // becomes 'meta_value_num'
    'order' => 'ASC',

    // category filter
    'tax_query' => $taxQuery,

    // date filter
    meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key' => 'date_%_start-date',
            'value' => $when,
            'compare' => '>=',
            'type' => 'NUMERIC'
        ),
        array (
            'key' => 'date_%_end-date',
            'value' => $when2,
            'compare' => '<=',
            'type' => 'NUMERIC'
        )
    )


);

$temp = $wp_query;
$wp_query = null;
$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: maybe you should add the post type ? such as : 'post_type' => 'portfolio'

Comment: Information like that is in the `wp_query`, I just stripped it down to the minimum I thought was needed as it's pretty big. I'll update the question with the full query in though, if it helps.

Comment: maybe it's an ACF beta issue.. you might want to post also on their official support [link]http://support.advancedcustomfields.com/